# Prevent the background from scrolling using an absolute position for the content

Tags: html, css

So I have been reading the folowing [article](https://blog.alexdevero.com/build-coming-soon-page-countdown/) and I have created the following example to support the questions.

```css
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

h1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
  height:100vh;
  background: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/257525.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* dark overlay */
.wrapper::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
}

.content{
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  top50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
  Let's write some text
  </h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  </div>
</div>
```

1. The first question is regarding the position of the text. For example, if we observe the code, the text is currently in front of the dark overlay. This is because we have used `position:absolute;` for the `.content` class. Removing it, will cause the text come behind the dark overlay. I fail to understand why this is the case, since I thought `::before` meant before the actual contents get displayed (i.e. first draw the overlay and then the contents).
2. The code contains an undesirable effect, which is when the `.content` `div` contains a lot of text. This causes the text to overflow and make the page scrollable, showing an empty background, rather than the image itself. It would be best if the background would not scroll with it and let just the text scroll.
3. Would there be a `position:relative;` and `z-index: 1;` approach possible to achieving the same result?

Thanks for clarifying my understanding of CSS.

Comment: A [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform. With your kind of rep, you should rather know that by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `:before` (or `::before`) means before the element's innerHTML. It has nothing to do with position context. Your `:before` pseudoelement in your example has absolute positioning itself, which will place it on top of static-ly positioned elements by default. If you remove `position: absolute` from your `.content`, it will have `position:static`, as that is the default.
2. You can scroll because the content div has additional text that is wrapping beyond the background image. You can add `overflow: auto` and `height: 100%` to `.content` to prevent it from growing beyond its container.
3. `position: relative` creates a new position context and allows z-indexing, but does not remove the element from the document flow in the way that `position: absolute` does. However, since you have defined the height, it would work in much the same way **in this very specific case*.

```
.content{
  color:#fff;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

h1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
  height:100vh;
  background: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/257525.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* dark overlay */
.wrapper::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
}

.content{
  color:#fff;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
  Let's write some text
  </h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, minima quod? Molestiae cumque sint veniam corrupti mollitia? Tenetur sint officia quod ex aspernatur? Blanditiis reiciendis, pariatur vero suscipit magnam deleniti!
  </div>
</div>
```